# How to run tests in my contrib module?

Tags: testing

I'm writing a contrib module but I can't find the documentation to run the tests - unit and functional. I know that I'm supposed to use PhpUnit, but I can't find examples of PhpUnit configuration files and more importantly, there is no resource on how to execute functional tests - i.e. having the module tested against a running Drupal instance.

I've been looking at some famous contrib modules like Paragraphs and there is nothing about running tests in their documentation - and no phpunit dependency at all. Which doesn't make sense to me since there are some functional tests implemented.

How are we supposed to provide tests for contrib modules?

Comment: The documentation for Drupal 8 is here, https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/phpunit

Answer (score 2):

You have to include phpunit/phpunit package in composer, alredy done if you took [default drupal installation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-install-drupal-and-manage-dependencies#download-core) :

```
composer require phpunit/phpunit --dev
```

A file should be filled which describe yours testsuites, generally phpunit.xml

It looks like this `./phpunit.xml` :

```
<phpunit bootstrap="web/core/tests/bootstrap.php" colors="true"
         beStrictAboutTestsThatDoNotTestAnything="true"
         beStrictAboutOutputDuringTests="true"
         beStrictAboutChangesToGlobalState="true"
         checkForUnintentionallyCoveredCode="false"
         printerClass="\Drupal\Tests\Listeners\HtmlOutputPrinter">

<php>
  <ini name="error_reporting" value="32767"/>
  <ini name="memory_limit" value="-1"/>
  <env name="SIMPLETEST_BASE_URL" value="http://drupal-8.localhost"/>
  <env name="SIMPLETEST_DB" value="mysql://drupal-8:drupal-8@localhost/drupal-8"/>
  <env name="BROWSERTEST_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY" value="/var/www/sites/default/simpletest"/>
</php>
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="testname1">
      <directory>web/modules/custom/your_module/tests</directory>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="testname2">
      <directory>web/modules/custom/your_module2/tests</directory>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

In this example, drupal is located in `./web/` directory with `./vendor/`, both in root path (`./`) .

You can add test for contrib module, but they are already tested (if they contain tests) when authors are pushing their sources to drupal.org ( https://www.drupal.org/pift-ci-job/1339317 ) :

```
<testsuite name="toolbar">
    <directory>./web/modules/contrib/admin_toolbar/tests/src/FunctionalJavascript</directory>
</testsuite>
```

Then you can run tests with :

```
./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit
```

To use a specific description file :

```
./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit -c phpunit-other.xml
```

To run a specific testsuite :

```
./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --testsuite=testname1
```